# can't access maven project resource in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven

the below is my configuration

project directory

the below image is my project structure. Spring Maven project

[image]
**Servlet-context.xml**

i have done resource mapping

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
 
 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />

 <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 


 <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.manjunath.controller" />
 
</beans:beans>
```

**home.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <link href="/resources/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  
</head>
<body>
<h1>Home page:${pageContext.request.contextPath}</h1>

<h2 id="kaka">Hi this is manjunath</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- Processes application requests -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and there is no error in project and successfully executed
**but resource files are not mapping**

Comment: A standard Maven folder structure, puts the static resources like js and css files into the `webapp\resources` folder.
Anyway, you need to put your files under webapp dir.

Comment: Still i am not able to access the resources

Comment: Update your question, and provide more info, like web.xml

Comment: hi i updated project structure and added web.xml

Comment: I guess that all your request are routed to you servlet, therefore you can't access your resource. 

Try to map your servlet to /page

Comment: please explain i did't get

Comment: thanks J.Mengelle for correction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is only 1 mistake in your code

In the page you need to give css link like below

```
<link href="resources/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Just remove the `/` from href.